# how to submit username and password in ionic4 using simple submit button

Tags: ionic4

In my Ionic 4 framework, I want to submit a form when I click on the submit button.

I want to get username and password when I click on the submit button.

```js
`enter code here`

this is my ts file in ionic4

import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
 username:string;
 password:string;
 
 constructor()
 {
 
   }
   
login() {
  console.log(this.username);
  console.log(this.password);
  
}
  
  }



html file in ionic4
```

```html
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title>Home</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<form (ngSubmit)='login()'>
 <ion-item>
  <ion-input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
  <ion-input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button type="submit">Submit</ion-button>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

Place a form in html with input field for username and password. We will bind the username and password variables with ngModel. When the button is sumbitted, the login() function is activated.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()">
  <ion-input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
  <ion-input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
  <ion-button type="submit">Submit</ion-button
</form>
```

### TS

Declare username and password variables and place the login function with other logic here.

```
login() {
  console.log(this.username);
  console.log(this.password);
  // other logic
}
```

---

### EDIT

Example of `ion-input` inside `ion-grid`

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
     <ion-col size="12"> <!-- Control width of form in grid -->
       <form (ngSubmit)="login()">
         <ion-row>
           <ion-col size="12">
             <ion-input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
           </ion-col>
           <ion-col size="12">
             <ion-input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
           </ion-col>
           <ion-col size="12">
         <ion-button type="submit">Submit</ion-button
           </ion-col>
         </ion-row>
       </form>
     </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```

Comment: compiled successfully but cant get any form :(

Comment: @simsingh What do you mean? Can't you see the input fields? Can you clarify

Comment: i am unable to see input fields....plzz check my code and tell me where i am doing wrong

Comment: @simsingh can't spot the error in your code. I have updated my answer with an example of a form inside an ionic grid. Hope it helps!